# Traverse a branch top to bottom. [root and destination node given]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How to traverse a branch of n-ary tree if you just have a source node and a destination node. Rest everything can be assumed. Given that source node is ancestor of that destination node.

Comment: Do u want a path from source to destination?

Comment: DFS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: yes
@Nik I just have a source node say the root of tree and I want to go to a desired node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved the problem by just maintaining a parent pointer for each node.
So every node will just point to its parent node. In other words each branch is maintained as a linked list.
This linked list will have some properties like many nodes can point to one node but one node is not pointing to more than one node.
Just having the address of any node I can traverse whole branch from bottom to root.

Answer (score 0):

yes dfs is one way we can traverse the nodes, compare each with destination node till u find one n return... in case u don't find ( keep a flag to keep track) u can throw an exception or do whatever u wish to do to handle it.

Comment: I want to traverse that branch specifically and wanna change some of the properties of node in that particular branch.
In dfs you need to traverse every for comparison

Comment: first u need to identify the branch for that u need to do dfs, in dfs u can store the nodes on stack .... when u reach the destination node... u can empty the stack to know the branch... and do whatever changes u wish to

Comment: how to efficiently find the branch??

Comment: if u r making the tree earlier in ur program, than keep track of parents ( in java u can use a hashmap with 'node' as key and 'parent' as its value)... so when given a destination u need to access the parents recursively till u reach the source (which acc. to ur question is an ancestor... so wud be a parent of some node in the path)

Answer (score 0):

BFS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 0):

Given that the source node is an ancestor of the destination node you should be able to traverse the parent pointers of the destination until you find the source node.